# How do I solve this error that is saying I do not have an id for my users class and not connecting it to messages class when I feel like I have them

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I am trying to create a login function on my website. I have created a user and messages class as well and created functions in my server and crud files for these classes. I keep receiving this error. NoForeignKeysError
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.sent_messages - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
here are my classes:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(50))
    sent_messages = db.relationship("Message", foreign_keys="[Message.sender_id]")
    received_messages = db.relationship("Message", foreign_keys="[Message.recipient_id]")

    def __init__(self, user_id, email, password, sent_messages, received_messages):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.sent_messages = sent_messages
        self.received_messages = received_messages

class Message(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "messages"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    date_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    sender_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    recipient_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable = False)
```

Any help?

I thought that the user account would be created but it is not as I keep receiving errors.

Comment: Create your relationships on the `Message` class instead of on the `User` class.